# Simplifying mysql fulltext search

Tags: mysql

To do text search for `wordA`, `wordB` and `wordC` right now I'm doing it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    mytable 
WHERE
    MATCH (field1) AGAINST ('wordA' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR
    MATCH (field1) AGAINST ('wordB' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR
    MATCH (field1) AGAINST ('wordC' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Is there a more compact way of writing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just worked out this will work too

```
SELECT * FROM 
    mytable 
WHERE
    MATCH (field1) AGAINST ('wordA/wordB/wordC' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```